# How can I create arc progress bar using xml layouts in android without extra libraries?

Tags: android, xml, layout, progress

I know this is not a new question but I didn't find any proper solution yet. How can I make a progress bar like the photo using native android xml layouts and no 3rd party libraries?

[image: arc progress bar]

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your custom `View`. Then in `onDraw()` method just draw on `canvas` whatever you want. There is `canvas.drawArc()` function.

Comment: thank you, Yes I did it, but I want to know if there is any way to draw an arc with XML shapes?

Comment: Draw circle, cut bottom part

Comment: can you give an example please

Comment: I just realized that's is nearly impossibly to do via xml